# ¿Es posible cambiar el tipo de un campo en un documento MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql

Estoy intentando cambiar el tipo de un campo en una base de datos no relacional como es MongoDB, es decir, en un documento que está tipo int estoy intentando cambiarlo a string, pero no sé como realizarlo.

¿En MongoDB es posible mediante código cambiar el tipo de campo una vez ya está creado y con datos?

Todo esto lo estoy intentando realizar desde jupyter notebook utilizando el código Python.

Comment: Yo siempre trabajo con `mongoengine`, me permite dar cierta estructura a mis colecciones. aqui tienes un ejemplo de como le darias el tipo en la definicion de una clase que es el par en la base de datos. https://stackoverflow.com/q/63696868/4959345

Comment: *¿En MongoDB es posible mediante código cambiar el tipo de campo una vez ya está creado y con datos?* Parece que no te has molestado en **INVESTIGAR**. Eso aparece en la [documentación](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/#use-an-aggregation-pipeline-for-updates) de MongoDB. Existe para algo. Te invito a leer [ask] y [mre]. La idea del sitio es que las preguntas sean específicas y no tan abiertas y genéricas. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En phyton lo puedes hacer así, puedes usar `$toString` para la conversión:

```
collection.update_many(
   filter={},
   update=[
     {
       $set: {
         key: {
           $toString: "$key"
         }
       }
     }
   ],
)
```

Te dejo un ejemplo en MongoPlayground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/9-LMMa1HqXx

Comment: Solo quería ayudar al compañero y darle una luz de como solucionar su problema. De igual manera ya ajusté la sintaxis a pyhton. Saludos

Comment: @CandidMoe ya ajusté el código a python

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero!!